# converting an int array into a string

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm currently working on a project that is mostly run on a Raspberry pi, but has tasks complete by microcontroller. Currently, my RPi is sending a string of integers separated by commas to a microcontroller (ESP 32 Thing plus), the microcontroller is then converting that into an intergern array and using those values to set the level of a PWM output. Simultaneously, the microcontroller is reading an analogue input and storing those values into another int array, this data needs to be sent back to the RPi. I've been trying for ages to convert this into a string to be sent back, which works for the most part using sprintf() and strcat(), but it only works when I have just the number values. It would be good to have commas separate the numbers, but as soon as I do that, I get a really weird out put and the numbers start changing from their actual value to "1792" or 44" and it cycles between them or if I us a float array then I get 6 variables correct and then the rest are changes to "512".

Its a lot to send but possibly better to see the whole thing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// variables to hold, parse and manipulate data
const byte numChars = 64;
const byte stringLength = 255;
char receivedChars[1000];
char tempChars[1000]; 
char messageFromPC[stringLength] = {0};
int MyArray[] = {};
int LaserMeasurmentArray[200] = {};
char LaserMeasurmentString[] = "";
int BrakeArray [60] = {10,200,600,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,500,0,0,0};
int AccelleratingArray [60] = {10,200,600,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,500,0,0,0};
int TimeStamps[200] = {};
char TimeStampString = '0';
int i = 0;
int SizeOfArray = 0;
int MyArraySize = 0;
int Counter = 0;
int CounterLaser = 0;

//Clutch/Brake Setup
int ClutchPin = 33;
int BrakePin = 27;
int ButtonPin = 32;
int ButtonState = LOW;
int Delay = 10;
int PWM = 1023;
const int LaserPin = A0;

//Millis variables 
unsigned long PreviousMillisAccel = 0;
unsigned long PreviousMillisLaser = 0;
unsigned long CurrentMillis = 0;
const int PeriodWrite = 8;
const int PeriodRead = 5;

//Action States
boolean newData = false;
boolean SendData = false;
boolean AccellerationInProgress = false;
boolean BrakingInProgress = false;

//============

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    //ledcSetup(ledChannel, freq, resolution);
    ledcSetup(1, 5000, 10);
    ledcSetup(2, 5000, 10);
    //ledcAttachPin(LED, ledChannel);
    ledcAttachPin(ClutchPin, 1);
    ledcAttachPin(BrakePin, 2);
    pinMode(LaserPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(ButtonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

//============

void loop() {
    
    recvWithStartEndMarkers();
    if (newData == true) {
        strcpy(tempChars, receivedChars);
        //Serial.print(receivedChars);
        //Serial.println();
        parseData();
        //showParsedData();
        //ButtonPress();
        
        ButtonState = HIGH;
        while (ButtonState == HIGH) {
          ButtonState = digitalRead(ButtonPin);
          }//while 
        Serial.println();
        Serial.print("Accellerating");
        Serial.println();
        PWMSignal();
        Serial.println();
        Serial.print("Deccellerating");
        Serial.println();
        PWMSignal2();
        newData = false;
        ButtonState = HIGH;
        while (ButtonState == HIGH) {
          ButtonState = digitalRead(ButtonPin);
          }//While
        SendReply();
    }
}

//============

void recvWithStartEndMarkers() {
    static boolean recvInProgress = false;
    static byte ndx = 0;
    char startMarker = '<';
    char endMarker = '>';
    char rc;

    while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
        rc = Serial.read();

        if (recvInProgress == true) {
            if (rc != endMarker) {
                receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
                ndx++;
                if (ndx >= stringLength) {
                    ndx = stringLength - 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
                recvInProgress = false;
                ndx = 0;
                newData = true;
            }
        }

        else if (rc == startMarker) {
            recvInProgress = true;
        }
    }
}

//============

void parseData() {      // split the data into its parts
  i = 0;
  String serialResponse = tempChars;
  char buf[sizeof(tempChars)];
  serialResponse.toCharArray(buf, sizeof(buf));
  char *p = buf;
  char *str;
  while ((str = strtok_r(p, ",", &p)) != NULL  && i < 1180 ){ // delimiter is the comma
      MyArray[i] = atoi(str);
      //Serial.println(str);
      MyArraySize = i;
      i++;
  }//While

}//parseData

//============

void showParsedData() {

  for(int i = 0; i < MyArraySize+1; i++){
  Serial.print(MyArray[i]);
  Serial.print(",");
  }//For
  Serial.println();
}

void PWMSignal(){
  int Counter = 0;
  CounterLaser = 0;
  CurrentMillis = millis();
  AccellerationInProgress = true;

  while(AccellerationInProgress == true) {
    CurrentMillis = millis();
    if (Counter == 60){
      AccellerationInProgress = false;
      }//if
    else if (CurrentMillis - PreviousMillisAccel >= PeriodWrite) {
      ledcWrite(1, AccelleratingArray[Counter]);
      //Serial.println(AccelleratingArray[Counter]);
      Counter = Counter + 1;
      PreviousMillisAccel = CurrentMillis;
      }//else if
      
    if (CurrentMillis - PreviousMillisLaser >= PeriodRead){
      LaserMeasurmentArray[CounterLaser] = analogRead(LaserPin);
      Serial.println(LaserMeasurmentArray[CounterLaser]);
      TimeStamps [CounterLaser] = CurrentMillis;
      PreviousMillisLaser = CurrentMillis;
      CounterLaser = CounterLaser + 1;
      }//if 
    }//While Accel

  ledcWrite(1, 0);
}//PWMSignal

void PWMSignal2() {
  int Counter = 0;
  BrakingInProgress = true;
  
  while(BrakingInProgress == true) {
    CurrentMillis = millis();
    if (Counter == 60){
      BrakingInProgress = false;
      }//if
    else if (CurrentMillis - PreviousMillisAccel >= PeriodWrite) {
      ledcWrite(2, BrakeArray[Counter]);
      //Serial.println(BrakeArray[Counter]);
      Counter = Counter + 1;
      PreviousMillisAccel = CurrentMillis;
      }//else if
      
    if (CurrentMillis - PreviousMillisLaser >= PeriodRead){
      LaserMeasurmentArray[CounterLaser] = analogRead(LaserPin);
      Serial.println(LaserMeasurmentArray[CounterLaser]);
      TimeStamps [CounterLaser] = CurrentMillis;
      PreviousMillisLaser = CurrentMillis;
      CounterLaser = CounterLaser + 1;
      
    }//if 
    }//While Accel

  ledcWrite(1, 0);
  ledcWrite(2, 0);
  
}//PWMSignal2


void SendReply() {
  //Serial.println("Laser Data");
  //Serial.println(sizeof(LaserMeasurmentArray));
  for (int i = 0; i<=200; i++){
    Serial.println(LaserMeasurmentArray[i]);
    }
  
   for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++){
    int buff = LaserMeasurmentArray[i];
    char str [7];
    sprintf(str,"%u" ,buff); 
    strcat(LaserMeasurmentString,str);
    strcat(LaserMeasurmentString, ",");
    
    }
  Serial.print(LaserMeasurmentString);
  
}//sendReply
```

If someone could point out what I am doing wrong or have misunderstood, that would be great, thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is when you put `","` in the array, it fills wrong, sends wrong, is there any error?

Comment: Yes, when I print the string to the monitor (or send it back to the pi) I can see that it has changed the values that were in the array.

Comment: Without commas I get this: 1950193719521955195519511957195519491953195519571946195419571953195319471947195919571965198319791951199019491971195119431942195319511951195119461957195119361958196319371953194319491954194219491947194119521949. and then when I include the commas I get this: 1957,1954,1951,1954,1792,44,1792,44,1792,44,1792,44,1792,44,1792,44,1792,44,1792,44,1792,44,1792,44,

Comment: I suggest you first set a size at `LaserMeasurmentString`, like `LaserMeasurmentString[400]`. I just tested the snippet that fills and printed it on the console and it worked.

Comment: Yep, thats gone and done, thank you.